When I am uploading with PlatformIO, why isn't there a prompt to reboot the microcontroller power supply?
Computer: MacBook Pro
Chip: Apple M3 Pro
macOS: Sequoia 15.2
platformio.ini information：
[env:STC89C52RC]
platform = intel_mcs51
board = STC89C52RC
upload_protocol = stcgal
monitor_speed = 115200
upload_speed = 256000
upload_port = /dev/cu.wchusbserial210

I'm using vs-code to learn the STC89C52RC microcontroller with the PlatformIO plugin, which is very handy.
But today I'm having a problem, as shown in the picture, before it would prompt me to reboot, now it keeps showing Uploding ..., only after I power off. May I ask what is the situation?
The problem remains unresolved, but in my attempts to solve it, I have discovered another phenomenon.
When I uploading manually, I get a reboot prompt with the following command:
stcgal -P stc89 -p /dev/tty.wchusbserial210 /Users/shawnmao/Documents/PlatformIO/Projects/Test/.pio/build/STC89C52RC/firmware.hex
However, there is still no prompt using PlatformIO, and I'm wondering why there was a prompt a few days ago, has anyone else had a similar problem?
I want to be prompted to reboot, not I don't know what to do and go try rebooting.
I have made no changes to the settings, configuration, and I want to be prompted to reboot.
Thank you all so much for your help.
No reboot prompt
Disconnecting and reconnecting only to be prompted
A prompt appears when manually uploading
Tried to fix it, but PlatformIO still won't prompt for it
Modified the uploading parameter.
uninstall plugin reinstall plugin.
Uninstall vs code reinstall vs code…
